# How to position TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

How can I shift the `system` node right of `control1` but vertically centered between `control1` and `control2`?

```
\tikzstyle{controller} = [draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=yellow!20, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]    
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1.5cm]
\tikzstyle{disturbance} = [draw=none, node distance=1.5cm, line width=0pt] 
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};    
\node [controller, right of=sum] (control1){Control1}; 
\node [controller, above of=control1] (control2) {Control2};
\node [block, right of= control1, node distance=5cm, yshift=-1.4cm] (system) {System};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `positioning` library instead of the deprecated input syntax `<direction> of =`. See this answer [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz) and also [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

Then, you can use the `calc` syntax to get the middle point of the two nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sum/.style={draw, circle, node distance=1.5cm},
               controller/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
               block/.style={draw, fill=yellow!20, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em}]
  \coordinate (input);
  \node [sum, right= of input] (sum) {};    
  \node [controller, right = of sum] (control1) {Control1}; 
  \node [controller, above = of control1] (control2) {Control2};
  \node [block, right= 5cm of {$(control1)!0.5!(control2)$}] (system) {System};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And please post full compilable code.